# Getting the domain name into an EC2 URL

Tags: amazon-ec2, nameservers

This is probably an incredibly simple question, but I haven't been able to find out what specifically I'm doing wrong here.

I have a site hosted on Amazon EC2, a domain name registered with GoDaddy, and Route 53 nameservers. Let's call the site domain.com...

I've set everything up with:

- The GoDaddy nameserver fields set to the Route 53 nameservers
- A hosted zone for domain.com on Route 53
- In this hosted zone, a record set
- In this record set, two A Records for "domain.com" and "www.domain.com", both of which point to the Elastic IP of my EC2 server

This works, and when I go to domain.com, I get redirected to my site. However, the url does not get labeled as "domain.com/index.php" but instead as "ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php".

What am I missing here?

As a PS, I just want to temporarily have domain.com route correctly -- I don't care about static IP at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup is correct. You have something in your application that is redirecting requests. Wordpress will redirect to the domain it was installed on, other application do the same thing. To fix you may have to update options in the database or in a config file.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely a redirect. I'm using a php header() function to redirect from my index page to a relative link. How do I prevent this from changing the domain name, and why does that happen at all? I assume I have to use .htaccess rewrite conditions?